# Magento Cloud Integration - js and css files

Tags: magento2, static-content, cloud

We have recently inherited a Magento 2 cloud environment that has a working production and staging.

We also have an integration environment that should have identical code to staging but neither the frontend or backend is working properly.

The css/js files for Integration are all returning 404's as it is trying to access the non-minified versions of these files while only the minified versions exist.

For example in the admin it tries to find ---/require.js which does not exist but if I manually go to ---/require.min.js the file exists.

Staging/Production both call to the .min.js version of files. Images are showing and css/js is there it is just not named what it is looking for. We have tried several of the standard things (clear cache, deploy static content) but no change. The deploy mode is set to production.

Is there a setting that controls this somewhere or some other likely culprit for why it would not look for the correct files.

Comment: Have you use Fastly cache? if use then clear fastly cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are turning on this configuration in backend

[image]

Here is the path you go if need :  **Stores->Configurations->Advanced->Developer**.

Comment: This setting doesn't show in Production mode in the admin section. It can be set in the env.php file which was what was happening in this case and caused the weirdness.